# Array not returning from a router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mongoose, react-hooks

I'm having some trouble getting some values from my database via express. On my server, I have this router call:

```
router.get('/list/:id', TokenController.isAValidToken, async (req, res) => {
    const { cardID } = req.query;

    try {
        if (cardID != null) {
            ...
        } else {
            const cards = await CardsController.getCardsForList(req.params.id);
            const orderItems = await OrderItemController.getOrderItemsForCardsInList(cards, req.params.id);
            console.log(orderItems); // <- This prints an array with the info I need
            res.json(orderItems);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    }
});
```

My getOrderItemsForCardsInList function has this:

```
static async getOrderItemForCardInList(cardID, listID) {
   return OrderItem.find({ card: cardID, list: listID }).exec();
}

static async getOrderItemsForCardsInList(cards, listID) {
   return Promise.all(cards.map((card) => OrderItemController.getOrderItemForCardInList(card, listID)));
}
```

On my client, I call the router function like this:

```
async function getOrderItemsForCardsInList(listID) {
    const token = await getToken();
    const response = await fetch(`${basePath}/order/list/${listID}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: getTokenAuthHeaders(token)
    });

    return response.json();
}

export default function useOrderItemsForCardsInList(cards) {
    const { listID } = useParams();

    return useQuery(['order', ...cards], () => {
        if (listID != null) {
            return getOrderItemsForCardsInList(listID);
        } else {
            throw Error('No list id defined');
        }
    });
}
```

And I call that custom hook over here:

```
const { orderdata } = useOrderItemsForCardsInList(cards.map((card) => card !== null && card._id));
console.log('Data', orderdata);
```

The problem is that `orderdata` is printing `undefined`, meaning that the values are not getting returned as they should, my theory is that probably I'm messing something up in my `useOrderItemsForCardsInList` custom hook.

Comment: is endpoint correct? `/list/:id` or `/order/list/:id`

Comment: It's correct, I have multiple routers, and ```order``` is the one that has the endpoint where the ```console.log(orderItems);``` is located

Comment: What if you do `const orderdata = useOrderItemsForCardsInList()`?